# Books on respect between partners

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, family-members

I have been told that there are good books for helping understand how to improve the respect I can give my [significant other](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_other). I have found a few online stores, but was wondering what sort of books I should be looking for?

Comment: Hello @Michael and welcome to MiYodeya. See below for a first answer. I hope I got your question right, if you have something specific in mind please [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/67397/edit) your question to be more precise

Comment: Hello @Michael. I see you have chosen to use the word "partner" in your question. Since that can apply to many different types of relationships, both business and personal, can you please clarify what type of partnership you are inquiring about.

Comment: Based on the use of the [tag:family-members] tag, I'll assume this is about a [SO](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_other) and edit to clarify as much. (I see the answerer thought so, too.) If I'm mistaken, Michael, please re-edit.

Answer (score 3):

When I was engaged, I read R' Volve's מאמרי הדרכה לחתנים and R' Chaim Friedlander's וידעת כי שלום אהלך. I re-read both of them after being married, and gained much more from them at that point. They address your topic of respect, as well as other important fundamentals of being a good husband. If you're up for Hebrew reading, they are both great places to start.

Comment: The OP is indeed looking for Hebrew seforim (see one of his answers in another comment) - he should have said so originally - so your answer should indeed be highly relevant

Answer (score 2):

Here are three books on Jewish marriage and respect between spouses which I would recommend, out of many I read

- [Made in Heaven: A Jewish Wedding Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0940118114) by R Aryeh Kaplan -- in my view the best guide to a Jewish wedding and through this to building the foundations of a strong Jewish couple
- [The Jewish Way in Love & Marriage by R Maurice Lamm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824604806) which also [available online here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/465140/jewish/The-Jewish-Way-in-Love-Marriage.htm) -- very accessible
- [Dear son: a father's wise guidance for wholesome human relationship, a happy marriage, and a serene home by Eliyohu Goldschmidt](http://artscroll.com/pbb/DRSP) -- written by a father for his son (the same exists for a woman, called [Dear daughter](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578192885.html))

Comment: HI many many thanks. I will look at these books, by partenr i mean my spouse... sorry :) I was reccomended a book by Rav Eliyahu a book called : בגן השלום i have afound a copy, but am still looking for options:  http://hekhalot.co.il/details.asp?id=1764

Answer (score 0):

There are several. Some of the best probably are the following:

1. [The Menuchah Principle in Marriage: The Pathway to Shalom Bayis](http://www.judaicapress.com/products/the-menuchah-principle-in-marriage) (Judaica Press, 2010) by  Shaya Ostrov
2. [The Garden of Peace: A Marital Guide for Men Only](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/5495321065) (Diamond Press, 2008) by  Rabbi Shalom Arush
3. [A Man's Responsibility: A Jewish Guide to Being a Son, a Partner in Marriage, a Father and a Community Leader](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1580233627) (Jewish Lights, 2008) by Rabbi Joseph B. Meszler
4. Shalom Bayis For The Jewish Husband by Rabbi Jeff Forsythe (online [here](https://www.shemayisrael.com/rabbiforsythe/shalombayis/kavod.htm))

Comment: Hey Renato Many thanks i'll go have a look.
Im actuially looking mainly for some stuff in hebrew :((
So iam looking at this site: http://www.hekhalot.co.il
If i find a good book there also ill let you know.
The book by Shaya Ostrov maybe i can find in hebrew do you think?
Mike

Comment: @Michael for sure R Arush (nr 2) exists in Hebrew - he writes in Hebrew. Check out http://www.breslev.co.il/store/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D.aspx?category=1&language=hebrew for instance